# Can't receive data messages from FCM

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app (written in swift) receive data messages when I debug it (and the device connected to my mac), but once I disconnect the device (iPhone 7, iOS 11.1), the messages are not received - even so I am able to receive "notification" messages.
why is it happen, and how can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not cross your firebase usage limit. Find it on given link:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ .
Add few logs that ensure that you are still receiving message.

Comment: FCM doesn't include any limit as far as I know.
Also, I am able to receive data messages when debugging, the problem occur when the device not connected to the laptop